# Display JSON data with Ionic 2/AngluarJS?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm fetching API data using AngularJS/Ionic 2. I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuc4dp0qHSc) guide and get it to properly log the data when I go to home.html. But when I try to actually display the data in home.html I can't get it to work.

data-provider.ts:

```
getRemoteData(){

this.http.get('https://api.example.com/?limit=10').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

}

home.ts:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.dataService.getRemoteData();
  }
```

This correctly logs JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "a", 
        "name": "ExampleA", 
        "price": "10"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "b", 
        "name": "ExampleB", 
        "price": "15"
    }
]
```

I've tried returning the data instead of logging the data, then creating a variable `data: any;` in the home.ts and outputting the data in home.html as `<p> data[0].name </p>` but I kept getting the error message, `Can't read property '0' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two point: you have either to assign the value from the request to a component's property and in the template wait for this property to be assigned.

Your service/provider should be (only):

```
getRemoteData(){

  return this.http.get('https://api.example.com/?limit=10')
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

you shouldn't subscribe to the observable in it. Do this in the component:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.dataService.getRemoteData().subcribe( response => this.data = response);
}
```

in the template, as mentioned before, check if the 'data' exists:

```
<p *ngIf="data">data[0].name </p>
```

Comment: Should add a return type for the method definition. getRemoteData() :Observable<any>{} will complete the answer :)

Comment: @PrithiviRaj thanks for the reminder!! I have edited the post with your tip :-)

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I'm not following completely how and where to assign the value `.getRemoteData()` returns. I've used the code you've provided and added `data: any;` to home.ts like this: `export class HomePage { data: any; constructor(private dataService: DataProvider) { } ionViewDidLoad(){ this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe( response => this.data = response); }` I'm still getting `Cannot read property '0' of undefined.`

Comment: @AdamDedanga are you using data[0]?.name in the template? If so, do not do this. Use the another markup (with the ngIf)